# Ubuntu and bcrypt

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, vagrant, bcrypt

When I trying run this command:

```
gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.10'
```

After that, I get this error:

```
current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@app2/gems/bcrypt-3.1.10/ext/mri
make "DESTDIR="
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
compiling crypt_blowfish.c
compiling wrapper.c
compiling crypt.c
compiling crypt_gensalt.c
linking shared-object bcrypt_ext.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

What I did to solve this problem:

> 1. reinstall ruby via rvm
> 2. updated and installed packages:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev make g++ gcc
```

after that, still get the same error

My environment:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ lsb_release -r
Release:    14.04
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ rvm -v
rvm 1.26.11 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

**Question:** How I can to install bcrypt gem?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Did you run distro-upgrade after apt-get update

Comment: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` - 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Install `libgmp3-dev` package.

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

It should do the trick.