# Docker-registry v2 with tls and basic auth behind nginx authentication error

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04, docker-compose, bcrypt, docker-registry

Short: I can't login on my docker-registry (hosted on ubuntu-vm (14.04LTS) in a servercenter) from the outside (my local computer running MAC) using a my.domain.ch name.

I *can* successfully login from the ubuntu-machine (vm-2) running the registry with 'docker login http://localhost:5000'

**This is my setup:**

vm-1: nginx/1.10.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 acting as reverse proxy (no docker installed here):

```
upstream registry {
    server vm-2:5000 fail_timeout=5s;
}

server {
 listen 80;
 server_name my.domain.ch; # server_name ;
 return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
 listen 443 ssl;
 server_name my.domain.ch; # server_name ;

 charset utf-8;
 keepalive_timeout 5;
 add_header Docker-Distribution-Api-Version registry/2.0 always;
 ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/key.pem;

 ssl_ecdh_curve          secp521r1;

 ssl_protocols           TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers       on;
 ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCMSHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:EC$

 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
 proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
 proxy_set_header Docker-Distribution-Api-Version registry/2.0;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_read_timeout 900;

 location / {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
    proxy_pass https://registry;
 }
}
```

vm-2 docker-registry on Ubuntu 14.04 acting as registry host.

`Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638`

`docker-compose version 1.7.0, build 0d7bf73`

`docker-registry version 2.5.1`

These are

- /opt/docker-registry/auth (htaccess)
- /opt/docker-registry/certs (key and cert)
- /opt/docker-registry/data (empty)
- /opt/docker-registry/docker-compose.yml

docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
registry:
  restart: always
  image: registry:2
  ports:
   - 5000:5000
 environment:
    REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /certs/cert.pem
    REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /certs/key.pem
    REGISTRY_AUTH: "htpasswd"
    REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: basic-realm
    REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/htpasswd
    REGISTRY_LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
 volumes:
   - /opt/docker_registry/data:/var/lib/registry
   - /opt/docker_registry/certs:/certs
   - /opt/docker_registry/auth:/auth
```

From my MAC I try

```
docker login https://my.domain.ch
Username: MyUserName
Password:
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://my.domain.ch/v2/ failed with status: 401 Unauthorized
```

My **research** showed me that:

[David Daeschler](https://daviddaeschler.com/2016/01/18/docker-registry-auth-issues/) wrote that docker only supports basic auth with bcrypt. (I tried with apache-md5, md5 and crypt all did not work). So I use bcrypt for my htacces as suggested.

My docker-registry log:

```
registry_1  | time="2016-09-22T10:01:00.809076941Z" level=debug msg="authorizing request" go.version=go1.6.3 http.request.host=mydomain.ch http.request.id=f1b0ccda-2d03-4480-aaf8-b7248acaed5f http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.127 http.request.uri="/v2/" http.request.useragent="docker/1.12.1 go/go1.6.3 git-commit/23cf638 kernel/4.4.20-moby os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.1 \\(darwin\\))" instance.id=59b4a38a-307e-446d-9f8a-3618c35bb6bb service=registry version=v2.5.1

registry_1  | time="2016-09-22T10:01:00.811894104Z" level=error msg="error authenticating user \"MyUserName\": authentication failure" go.version=go1.6.3 http.request.host=my.domain.ch http.request.id=f1b0ccda-2d03-4480-aaf8-b7248acaed5f http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.127 http.request.uri="/v2/" http.request.useragent="docker/1.12.1 go/go1.6.3 git-commit/23cf638 kernel/4.4.20-moby os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.1 \\(darwin\\))" instance.id=59b4a38a-307e-446d-9f8a-3618c35bb6bb service=registry version=v2.5.1

registry_1  | time="2016-09-22T10:01:00.812631504Z" level=warning msg="error authorizing context: basic authentication challenge for realm \"basic-realm\": authentication failure" go.version=go1.6.3 http.request.host=my.domain.ch http.request.id=f1b0ccda-2d03-4480-aaf8-b7248acaed5f http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr=83.xxx.xxx.127 http.request.uri="/v2/" http.request.useragent="docker/1.12.1 go/go1.6.3 git-commit/23cf638 kernel/4.4.20-moby os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.1 \\(darwin\\))" instance.id=59b4a38a-307e-446d-9f8a-3618c35bb6bb service=registry version=v2.5.1

registry_1  | xxx.xxx.xxx.11 - - [22/Sep/2016:10:01:00 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.0" 401 87 "" "docker/1.12.1 go/go1.6.3 git-commit/23cf638 kernel/4.4.20-moby os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.1 \\(darwin\\))"
```

The nginx-log:

```
2016/09/22 09:14:34 [crit] 13318#0: *8 crypt_r() failed (22: Invalid argument), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.127, server: my.domain.ch, request: "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1", host: "my.domain.ch"
```

The **reason for this error** is covered by this answer [from a Docker.com guy](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/29). (in short: Hunting this down shows this is dependent on the version of gcc shipped with debian. )

What I know from the logs & errors is:

- It has correctly forwarded the request
- Port is open and accepting request
- TLS works & certs are correct - it uses v2 of the api
- Must have to do with htaccess
- Must be a problem with nginx. Hence locally it works

**How can I make nginx understand bcrypt?**
**Or is the error somewhere else?**

Thanks for any help
SWiggels

**Edit:**

[Found this](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/655) from a docker.com guy:

```
I'm not sure if this will help, but we've become tired of dealing with nginx's edge cases for new users, so registry 2.1 will come with htpasswd based basic auth support.
```

As of using docker-registry v2.5.1 basic auth should work.

I installed `sudo apt-get install apache2-utils`on *vm-1*. I thought it might bring bcrypt with. It didn't work.

When installing bcrypt explicitly (`sudo apt-get install bcrypt`) I get `bcrypt is already the newest version.`

Adding `sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34568345/ubuntu-and-bcrypt) didn't work as well.

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833583/nginx-gives-an-internal-server-error-500-after-i-have-configured-basic-auth/35834603#35834603) auth_basic (of nginx? or basic auth in general?) does not support bcrypt. But the only encryption allowed by docker-registry is bcrypt for htaccess passwords.

Seen [read here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46883/is-every-hash-format-that-nginx-accepts-for-http-basic-auth-weak-against-brute-f) nginx can't handle bcrypt password hashes.

**Is it impossible to have a docker-registry v2.5.1 behind a nginx 1.10.1?**

Comment: Hello, did you got a fix for this issue. I am facing the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130976/private-docker-registry-with-self-signed-tls-certificates-not-accepting-valid-ba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still got no hint how I could fix my problem. Hence I got a workaround: I configured the firewall to forward the port directly to machine running the registry. So I can connect from the outside to my registry using the domainname.

If anyone got an idea how to make it run using nginx I would appreciate an answer.